# How to properly remove images for animations in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

im trying to create a simple space invaders game. This is my first ever game, and so im having some issues. The invaders is a rectangle object with an image of the oldschool invader. In each frame im drawing those boxes 15 pixels to the right, and then using root.getChildren().remove(), to remove the sprites in each frame. But it causes some weird behaviour. It kind of looks like it isnt being removed quickly enough, and so just when i launch the app it kind of explodes, and after that there seems to be a little bit of latency causing two images to be displayed constantly.

I guess it would probably help for you to see it yourself and so i will post all of my files here.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Space invaders");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene game = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

        Images images = new Images();

        // Make canvas and add it to primaryStage
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280,720);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        new AnimationTimer() {

            int move = 0;
            private long lastUpdate = 0;
            ArrayList<Sprite> enemies = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                if (now - lastUpdate >= 150_000_000) {

                    int spacing = 0;

                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
                            root.getChildren().remove(enemies.get(i));
                            enemies.remove(i);
                        }
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
                        System.out.println(ioobe.toString());
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                            Sprite enemy = new Sprite(60 * i + spacing + move, 43 * j, 60, 43, "enemy", true, images.getEnemy1());
                            enemies.add(enemy);
                            root.getChildren().add(enemy);
                        }
                        spacing += 15;
                    }
                    move += 5;

                    lastUpdate = now;

                }
            }
        }.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(game);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If you want to run the program yourself, her is the Sprite class:

```
public class Sprite extends Rectangle {

    private String type;
    private Boolean alive;

    public Sprite(int x, int y, int w, int h, String type, boolean alive, Image image) {
        this.setTranslateX(x);
        this.setTranslateY(y);
        this.setWidth(w);
        this.setHeight(h);
        this.type = type;
        this.alive = alive;
        this.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Boolean getAlive() {
        return alive;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, i have no idea why i thought i needed to remove the sprites in each animation. I have now updated my code and simply update the position of the already existing sprites, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just not the way the scene graph is supposed to be used. Why do you constantly remove and re-add your sprites? Why don't you just update their positions via the setTranslateX/Y which you are already using anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        root.getChildren().remove(enemies.get(i));
        enemies.remove(i);
    }
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
    System.out.println(ioobe.toString());
}
```

A correct implementation wouldn't require you to catch a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't know why this would throw such an exception though, since the check `i < enemies.size()` should ensure the index is valid.

Note however that this skips every other list element:

First you remove the first element of `enemies` from both lists (the one at index 0). This results in all elements remaining in the `enemies` list to be shifted to the left, i.e. the one that was at index 1 before the removal is now at index `0`. Since you increment the index after each loop iteration, all elements at odd indices are skipped.

There's a simpler way of implementing this btw:

```
root.getChildren().removeAll(enemies);
enemies.clear();
```

#### Note

Recreating your sprites in every frame should be avoided. The memory requirement of `Node`s doesn't make them objects you should throw away, if this can be avoided. Otherwise the garbage collector will be kept busy cleaning up the objects you "throw" away at best and an `OutOfMemoryException` happens at worst...
Reuse the sprites and modify the properties instead.

Also I recommend going with `ImageView` instead of `Rectangle`s filled with `ImagePattern`. You can adjust the size using the `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` properties.